# Use fnmatch.filter to filter files by more than one possible file extension

Tags: python, filesystems

Given the following piece of python code:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.png'):
        pass
```

How can I filter for more than one extension? In this special case I want to get all files ending with *.png, *.gif, *.jpg or *.jpeg.

For now I came up with

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for extension in ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']:
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.' + extension):
            pass
```

But I think it is not very elegant and performant.

Someone has a better idea?

Comment: Should be good, but a `tuple` would be better here (nitpicking!) `('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png')`.

Comment: @A A: Why is a tuple better in this case?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you only need to check extensions (i.e. no further wildcards), why don't you simply use basic string operations?

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png')):
            pass
```

Comment: thanks - that was a quite obvious solution - but i did not see it =)

Comment: Beware that this method is case sensitive so for instance the file named `annoying.GIF` will not be included in the above example. 

This can be solved by normalizing the filename: `... if filename.lower().endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png')) ... `

Answer (score 9):

I think your code is actually fine.  If you want to touch every filename only once, define your own filtering function:

```
def is_image_file(filename, extensions=['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png']):
    return any(filename.endswith(e) for e in extensions)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in filter(is_image_file, files):
        pass
```

Comment: Are you sure this would make a difference? Why not define a tuple (it will be created once only, right?) and not bother with all this? (Just asking!)

Comment: @AA: In your code, the tuple will be created in each iteration of the outer loop.  In my code, the list will be created only once.  I don't think the performance difference is relevant here.  My suggestion is more about code readability -- yours is fine as well.

Comment: Aah indeed. I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: @AA: Of course I could include the `"."` part in the list of extensions.  Well, I like that, I'll edit my post :)

Answer (score 6):

This would be a better way, perhaps because you are not calling `+` repeatedly and using a `tuple` instead of `list`.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for extension in ('*.jpg', '*.jpeg', '*.gif', '*.png'):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, extension):
            pass
```

A `tuple` is better because you are not going to modify the extension once you have created them. You are just using to iterate over them.

Answer (score 6):

I've been using this with a lot of success.

```
import fnmatch
import functools
import itertools
import os

# Remove the annotations if you're not on Python3
def find_files(dir_path: str=None, patterns: [str]=None) -> [str]:
    """
    Returns a generator yielding files matching the given patterns
    :type dir_path: str
    :type patterns: [str]
    :rtype : [str]
    :param dir_path: Directory to search for files/directories under. Defaults to current dir.
    :param patterns: Patterns of files to search for. Defaults to ["*"]. Example: ["*.json", "*.xml"]
    """
    path = dir_path or "."
    path_patterns = patterns or ["*"]

    for root_dir, dir_names, file_names in os.walk(path):
        filter_partial = functools.partial(fnmatch.filter, file_names)

        for file_name in itertools.chain(*map(filter_partial, path_patterns)):
            yield os.path.join(root_dir, file_name)
```

Examples:

```
for f in find_files(test_directory):
    print(f)
```

yields:

```
.\test.json
.\test.xml
.\test.ini
.\test_helpers.py
.\__init__.py
```

Testing with multiple patterns:

```
for f in find_files(test_directory, ["*.xml", "*.json", "*.ini"]):
    print(f)
```

yields:

```
.\test.json
.\test.xml
.\test.ini
```

Answer (score 4):

This isn't really elegant either, but it works:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.png') + fnmatch.filter(files, '*.jpg') + fnmatch.filter(files, '*.jpeg') + fnmatch.filter(files, '*.gif'):
        pass
```

Comment: @melroy-van-den-berg No you cannot do this.

Comment: @milembar ok, I see. What about: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5351860/518879 makes it more readable maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Internally, `fnmatch` users regular expressions. And there's a method that makes a regex from an fnmatch pattern — [`fnmatch.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.translate). This may also give a little speed-up.

```py
import fnmatch
import os
import re

image_exts = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']
image_re = re.compile('|'.join(fnmatch.translate('*.' + e) for e in image_exts))
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in files:
        if image_re.match(filename):
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am using to filter files in apache log directories.
Here I exclude errors flles

```
rep_filters = [now.strftime("%Y%m%d")]
def files_filter(liste_fic, filters = rep_filters):
    s = "(fic for fic in liste_fic if fic.find('error') < 0"
    for filter in filters:
        s += " and fic.find('%s') >=0 " % filter
    s += ")"
    return eval(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
# pattern_list = ['*.jpg', '__.*']
def checkFilepatter(filename, pattern_list):
    for pattern in pattern_list:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, pattern):
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to check if `my_file` matches any of the file masks defined in `patterns`:

```py
import fnmatch

my_file = 'my_precious.txt'
patterns = ('*.txt', '*.html', '*.mp3')


if [pat for pat in patterns if fnmatch.fnmatch(my_file, pat)]:
    print('We have a match!')
else:
    print('No match')
```

Answer (score 0):

The clearest solution is:

```py
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in files:
        _, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if ext in ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png']:
            ...
```

or, using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html),

```py
for path in pathlib.Path(directory).glob('**/*'):
    if path.suffix in ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png']:
        ...
```