# Removing brackets in filenames using Python across different file extensions

Tags: python, brackets

I have a few text, pdf, and doc files that have brackets and I wish to remove them in the file names.

For eg. [Alpha].txt --> Alpha.txt

The below code works, but it only works on specifically one file extension. Is there a way to include .pdf and .doc files within the same code?

```
import os, fnmatch

#Set directory of locataion; include double slash for each subfolder.
file_path = "C:\\Users\\Mr.Slowbro\\Desktop\\Source Files\\"

#Set file extension accordingly
files_to_rename = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(file_path), '*.txt')

for file_name in files_to_rename:
    file_name_new = file_name.replace('[', '')    
    os.rename(file_path + file_name, file_path + file_name_new)
    os.rename(file_path + file_name_new, file_path + file_name_new.replace(']', ''))
```

Comment: Perhaps you can try using *.* instead of *.txt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use fnmatch.filter to filter files by more than one possible file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351766/use-fnmatch-filter-to-filter-files-by-more-than-one-possible-file-extension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple for all files. Just replace `'*.txt` with `*.*`. The `*.*` means any file name with any file extension:

```
import os, fnmatch

#Set directory of locataion; include double slash for each subfolder.
file_path = "C:\\Users\\Mr.Slowbro\\Desktop\\Source Files\\"

#Set file extension accordingly
files_to_rename = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(file_path), '*.*') #All files included

for file_name in files_to_rename:
    file_name_new = file_name.replace('[', '')    
    os.rename(file_path + file_name, file_path + file_name_new)
    os.rename(file_path + file_name_new, file_path + file_name_new.replace(']', ''))
```

For specific extensions, just combine the lists:

```
import os, fnmatch

#Set directory of locataion; include double slash for each subfolder.
file_path = "C:\\Users\\Mr.Slowbro\\Desktop\\Source Files\\"

#Set file extension accordingly
files_to_rename = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(file_path), '*.txt') + fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(file_path), '*.pdf') + fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(file_path), '*.doc')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *.* instead of *.txt

```
files_to_rename = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(file_path), '*.*')
```