How to clip cell output in Jupyter notebook using nbconvert
I am using nbconvert to convert a Jupyter notebook to pdf using the command:
jupyter nbconvert --to webpdf --allow-chromium-download filename.ipynb
In some cells, I have printed a very long output, which is automatically clipped in the Jupyter notebook. However, the output is not clipped in the pdf output, resulting in a huge pdf of thousands of pages. Of course I can adapt the code to remove the output, but is there an option in nbconvert to also clip the cell output to a maximum length automatically?
Here is a minimal working example, these are the cells of a notebook Playground.ipynb :
# print long cell output that gets clipped in the notebook, but not in the pdf
for i in range(1000):
    print(i)

# convert to pdf with nbconvert
!jupyter nbconvert --to webpdf --allow-chromium-download Playground.ipynb

The Jupyter notebook automatically clips the output. However, when exporting this as pdf, I get too many pages because it is not clipped.
I searched the documentation and internet, but could not find the solution yet.

You seem to not have a good grasp on what is going on. The data isn't being clipped by Jupyter. If it was, it wouldn't be showing up later in the PDF because it wouldn't be there for jupyter nbconvert to access it. When you look at the notebook in Jupyter, it is just limiting the view for you to be convenient when running the notebook. I think if you save the notebook and look at the code in it using a text code editor you would see that. Or just compare the size of the .ipynb file with such a case verse one without such a case. Or look at an example in nbviewer.

 Because you aren't understanding what is going on it comes across that you are making an XY problem here. See here for what that is and why you should be avoiding it. We don't want to answer something that isn't really what you want to do because you'll turn around and say, "Oh, that isn't really what I want to do. I'll do Z."

If you did really want to do this what you seek is preprocessors in jupyter nbconvert, here is an example use. Personally, nbformat allows more Pythonic handling of all sorts of aspects of notebooks because it has all the concepts of notebook reading and saving & the cells and types of cells baked in. It would be an intermediate processing step you could run to handle the long output as you wish before using jupyter convert. nbformat is a nice tool in your toolbox for dealing with Jupyter .ipynb files programmatically. ...

  In regards to nbformat, I have many examples with code that you can see here and here.

@Wayne thanks for your replies. Of course you are right, the output is not really clipped, just hidden. Some background: I am implementing a neural network with my students and printing e.g. some weights to understand how they look like. Then my students need to convert to pdf for submitting their work. Of course, we could only print the first weights instead, but sometimes it is just helpful to look at the whole structure. So I am looking for an automated clipping method for the pdf instead.

@Wayne regarding nbformat, could you give some more details on how to do this? Sorry if this sounds like a stupid question to you, I am not a computer scientist and struggle with finding the right example among all the questions and sources you shared. I would highly appreciate further support!

Definitely not a stupid question.  However, though you provide a partial minimal  example using print(i). So I know to focus on long text in the output cell, I'd need some more details so I don't go doing a lot of extra things you don't need. What is the length you want to truncate to? Number of lines or length of the output text string overall? Is your cut off for acting the same as you want to truncate to? I could imagine the threshold for acting might be a little more lenient than your truncation set point because you may not want to trigger truncation if only 10 over.

@Wayne thanks for the reply! The length of the truncation is not really relevant, it could be e.g. 20-30 lines. But this is flexible, could also be a fixed length of text string, if that is more convenient. For my application, I only need to see the beginning of the printout in the pdf (so that I can see that my students printed the right thing). Any solution is fine as long as it prevents the thousands of pages of pdf output :)

This works using nbformat, which gets installed on your machine as part of Jupyter, for a notebook containing your demo cell example that has been executed:
##----USER SET OPTIONS----------------------------------------------##
truncation_trace_text = "...truncated..."
limit_number_lines = 11 # SET THE LIMIT OF LINES IN THE OUTPUT; EVERYTHING AFTER WILL BE TRUNCATED TO `...truncated...` or what `truncation_trace_text` set to
limit_to_working_directory = False # Set to `False` if want recursive and to process all notebooks in sub-directories below location of this script
edited_notebook_name_prefix = "TRUNCATED_" 
##----END OF USER SET OPTIONS SECTION-------------------------------##
import os
import fnmatch
import nbformat as nbf
pattern_to_match = "*.ipynb"


def truncate_long_notebook_output(filepath):
    '''
    Use nbformat to process all Jupyter `.ipynb` files to limt size of output
    to setting for `limit_number_lines`

    The removed part will be indicated with `truncation_trace_text`

    In relation to SO Post https://stackoverflow.com/q/79136448/8508004
    '''
    ntbk = nbf.read(filepath, nbf.NO_CONVERT)
    dirpath, notebook_name = os.path.split(filepath)
    cells_for_new_version = []
    limit_exceeded_for_notebook = False
    try:
        for cell in ntbk.cells:
            if cell.cell_type == "code":
                # MAIN PURPOSE: Take output in code cell and split on newlines & then 
                # truncate to setting for `limit_number_lines`, appending 
                # `truncation_trace_text`
                current_outputs = []
                
                num_lines = 0
                lines_in_current_output=0
                for idx,the_output_item in enumerate(cell.outputs):
                    if 'text' in the_output_item:
                        num_lines += len(str(the_output_item['text']).split('\n'))
                        # see if exceeds limit yet
                        if num_lines > limit_number_lines:
                            #print("\n".join(the_output_item['text'].split()[:limit_number_lines-lines_in_current_output]))
                            text_for_output = "\n".join(the_output_item['text'].split('\n')[:limit_number_lines-lines_in_current_output]) + '\n' + truncation_trace_text
                            the_output_item['text'] = text_for_output
                            current_outputs.append(the_output_item)
                            limit_exceeded_for_notebook = True
                            break
                        else:
                            current_outputs.append(the_output_item)
                            lines_in_current_output += num_lines
                    elif 'data' in the_output_item:
                        # JUST A STUB FOR NOW!!!!!!
                        # NOT QUITE IMPLEMENTED because OP example not related
                        # what it will do for now is stop adding things if this
                        # results in exceeding limit after first hit
                        current_outputs.append(the_output_item)
                        num_lines += len(str(the_output_item['data']).split('\n'))
                        # see if exceeds limit yet
                        if num_lines > limit_number_lines:
                            limit_exceeded_for_notebook = True
                            break
                    else:
                        current_outputs.append(the_output_item)
                        num_lines += len(str(the_output_item).split('\n'))
                        # see if exceeds limit yet
                        if num_lines > limit_number_lines:
                            limit_exceeded_for_notebook = True
                            break
                cell.outputs = current_outputs
                cells_for_new_version.append(cell)
            else:
                cells_for_new_version.append(cell)
        if limit_exceeded_for_notebook:
            new_ntbk_fp = os.path.join(dirpath, edited_notebook_name_prefix + notebook_name)
            print(f"Output in {filepath} above threshold seen and so a NEW version has been made: `{new_ntbk_fp}`.")
            new_ntbk = ntbk
            new_ntbk.cells = cells_for_new_version
            nbf.write(new_ntbk, new_ntbk_fp, version=nbf.NO_CONVERT)
        else:
            print(f"Output in {filepath} not above threshold and so no new version made.")
    except UnboundLocalError: # This will allow it to work if you put this code in a **FRESH** new notebook and run without saving first so that there is no cell to be read
        pass

if limit_to_working_directory:
    for filename in os.listdir('.'):
        if filename.upper().endswith((pattern_to_match.upper()[1:])): # based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/5351968/8508004
            # if it is a notebook then run the main function
            truncate_long_notebook_output(filename)
# `os.walk()` starting in the current working directory as 'root' based on 
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/54673093/8508004
else:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
        for filename in files:
            #if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, pattern_to_match): # based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/76996927/8508004
            if filename.upper().endswith((pattern_to_match.upper()[1:])) and '.local/share/Trash/' not in (os.path.join(root, filename)): # based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/5351968/8508004, plus don't want stuff in trash while working on with MyBInder session
                # if it is a notebook then run the main function
                truncate_long_notebook_output(os.path.join(root, filename))

There is an option, depending on the setting of the boolean limit_to_working_directory, to limit it to just the Jupyter .ipynb files you place in the same directory as this code, which can be in a .py file or notebook.
The idea would be you place this code in the directory where your notebook files are, or above them if the notebooks happen to be in directories and then run it. It will produce newly named files with the prefix 'Truncated_' for those that exceed the limit in any output in the notebook. I didn't want to clobber the originals, but you could do that if you prefer. I would test a develop it extensively before doing that though. Unless the original student copies are stored off somewhere else as well.
Then after this, you can make your PDFs with the truncated versions. I'd imagine automating that with programmatically tracking which ones to use in the conversion if you have a Truncated and untruncated pair.
Note that this code isn't quite fleshed out for other output yet. In particular, if you have dataframes it counts lines and just skips the next one in that output with no indicator about truncation. It doesn't truncate any dataframe itself in the middle, say if you have the options set to print all the rows.
I just went with your example code cell and didn't fully handle any others yet.
Additional details
nbformat has the concepts of notebooks and cells and cell type baked in so you can use them in your Python code. nbformat is included when you install Jupyter, and so need need for additional installations in order to use it.
For more about nbformat, see the top of my answer here.
Related:

For users who wanted to remove all output, see here.
'Here's a script to reduce size of a notebook with many png images' post on Jupyter Discourse


This is genious!! Exactly what I was hoping for. Thanks so much! I could never have done that on my own.
